# Question about conservation of energy and force

Tags: forces, energy

Feynman mentions in his book, *The Feynman Lectures on physics*

> Let us now illustrate the energy principle with a more complicated problem,
>   the screw jack shown in Fig. 4-5. A handle 20 inches long is used to turn the screw, which has 10 threads to the inch. We would like to know how much force would be needed at the handle to lift one ton (2000 pounds). If we want to lift the ton one inch, say, then we must turn the handle around ten times. When it goes around once it goes approximately 126 inches. The handle must thus travel 1260 inches, and if we used various pulleys, etc., we would be lifting our one ton with an unknown smaller weight W applied to the end of the handle. So we find out that W is about 1.6 pounds. This is a result of the conservation of energy.

I don't know where does this 126 inches would come from? And what does '10 threads to the inch' means?

Comment: @anupam: It's in Chapter 4-5

Comment: @anupam: Sorry, I messed that number up. It's *Page* 4-5 of Chapter 4.2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

X thread to the inch (or centimeter) means that if you measure an inch of the screw, you will find X grooves. The figure of 126 is an approximation of 3,14 (pi)* 2 * r (in this case 20 inches). The circumference of the circle inscribed by the end of the handle when you turn it one revolution.